# ExcelJS CSV Write Stream Not Writing with Large Dataset

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, stream, exceljs

I am using the **ExcelJS** library in my Node.js project to write a large dataset to a CSV file using the write stream feature. However, I am experiencing an issue where the write stream seems to fail when dealing with large datasets.

This works with small set of data and was able to upload to blob container.

Additional notes:
I was using `const csvBuffer = await workbook.csv.writeBuffer();` but it consumes a lot of memory while writing the file so i switched to streaming.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const stream = require('stream');

async function createAndUploadCSV() {
  // Create a new workbook and worksheet
  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

  // Add some sample data to the worksheet
  worksheet.columns = [
    { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 20 },
    { header: 'Age', key: 'age', width: 10 },
    { header: 'Email', key: 'email', width: 30 }
  ];

  for (let i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
    worksheet.addRow({ name: `User ${i}`, age: i, email: `user${i}@example.com` });
  }

  // Create a writable stream
  const writableStream = new stream.PassThrough();

  // Write workbook to the stream as CSV
  await workbook.csv.write(writableStream, { stream: true });

  // Create a BlobServiceClient to connect to Azure Blob Storage
  const connectionString = '';
  const containerName = 'app-reporting';
  const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

  // Create a unique name for the blob using a timestamp
  const blobName = `data-${Date.now()}.csv`;

  // Upload the CSV stream to Azure Blob Storage
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  const uploadResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(writableStream);

  console.log('File uploaded:', uploadResponse.requestId);
}

createAndUploadCSV().catch(console.error);
```